# Intuition about the harmonic mean when running multiple laps with different velocities

Tags: classical-mechanics, velocity

If I run two laps (= same distance) at different velocities $v_1$ and $v_2$, it is easy to derive algebraically that the mean velocity is given by the harmonic mean of $v_1$ and $v_2$
$$
\bar v_{\text{harm}} = \frac{2}{\frac{1}{v_1}+\frac{1}{v_2}} = \frac{2v_1v_2}{v_1+v_2}
$$
**My question is**: How can we understand the terms on the right-hand-side intuitively? If we write $v_2 = \alpha v_1$, the harmonic mean can be written as
$$
\frac{2v_1v_2}{v_1+v_2} = \frac{2v_2}{v_1+v_2} \cdot v_1 = \frac{2\alpha}{\alpha+1} \cdot v_1
$$
This looks like each term here should have an intuitive meaning but I can't see it.

Comment: I mean intuitively the mean velocity is v = S_total /  T_total = 2s / (s/v1 + s/v2) and then cancel s to get the harmonic mean. So the terms 1/v1 and 1/v2 are just the times t1 and t2 (divided by s).

Comment: Yes, I understand this. The problem is that I don't use the formula with the inverse speeds to actually calculate things. If I know I ran with $1.5 ms^{-1}$ during the first lap and doubled the speed afterwards, the formula with the alphas is more handy to use. But I can't remember it well and have to rederive it algebraically again and again because I don't have a feel for the meaning of the factors here.

Comment: You're dividing the product of $v_1$ and $v_2$ by their arithmetic mean. Both these things are symmetrical in $v_1$ and $v_2$. You know which way up the fraction goes because the units have to be those of velocity. Maybe these observations are enough to enable you to remember the formula, but the it's so easy to derive!